# How to style nested components in Angular 2 using host-context?

Tags: angular, sass

I have a component A, and I am using component B (which uses C & D components) inside the component A. I have the styling for A in a file called as a.scss which is as follows:

```
:host {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;

    .container-area {
        height: calc(100% - 30px);

        .col-area {
            display: flex;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .nested-area {
            width: 100%;

            B {
                top: auto;
                bottom: auto;
                left: auto;
                right: auto;

                C {
                    .container-c {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                    }
                }

                D {
                    border-color: red;
                    border-style: solid;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, the styling just gets applied to the component A and to the rest of the components partially. I can fix this by adding `/deep/`next to the `:host` and it works.

As, `/deep/` is currently deprecated, I was wondering to achieve the same using `:host-context`. But I am not sure how to do it. Could anyone help me with this?

And also, how can I overwrite a specific class say `.container-area` in a different .scss file? I am unable to overwrite the same class because, when I inspect the styles, for the `.container-area` looks like this `[nghost-c01] .container-area[_ngcontent-c01]`

Thank you.

Comment: `:host ::ng-deep.yourclass`

Comment: Isn't ng-deep deprecated?